# No match for 'operator==' em função find C

Tags: c

```
TipoApontador find (TipoItem x, TipoLista *lista){
   TipoApontador aux;
      if (lista->primeiro != NULL){
          aux = lista->primeiro;
          while (aux!=NULL){
             if (aux->item == x)
             return aux;
          aux = aux->prox;
          }
      }
  return NULL;
}
```

Galera,quando compilo essa função que criei junto com o código o compilador da erro no `if(aux->item == x)`. Vocês tem ideia do porque ?

> [Error] no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'TipoItem' and 'TipoItem')

Comment: É o que está escrito aí na mensagem de erro. Precisa saber algo mais?

Comment: Sim, eu na verdade não entendi, teria como explicar ?, modifiquei, pois copiei o errado a msg de erro

Comment: Você mudou a pergunta. o problema agora é que os tipos são incompatíveis, você não pode comprar laranjas com bananas. Mas não temos informações sobre os tipos para identificar o problema exato. Ah, e vocês está programando em C, mas usando um compilador de C++.

Comment: Vou postar o código todo

Comment: E o que quer fazer? É o problema que eu falei antes, não pode comparar laranja com banana, a solução é tirar essa comparação ou mudar para uma comparação que teste coisas iguais, mas depende do motivo de ter feito isto. Se você mandar procurar uma laranja em uma caixa de banana em linguagem dinâmica vai achar nada, em linguagem estática vai dizer que não pode procurar isso onde está procurando, então a solução é procurar a mesma coisa, mas não sei se esse é o seu objetivo. O código como um todo é um pouco confuso.

Comment: Meu objetivo naquela parte do código é verificar se o elemento existe na minha fila, se existir, retorna o item, se não existir, retorna null. Tem algum video ou link que possa me ajudar na implementação de uma fila dinâmica em c ? Pq ao meu entendimento, eu estaria comparando dois elementos TipoItem naquela passagem

Comment: @mahatt é importante [edit] e complementar a pergunta original com os detalhes pedidos nos comentários (e todos mais que puder acrescentar). Aqui tem umas dicas que talvez ajudem a elaborar o post e aumentar a chance de alguém entender seu problema e elaborar resposta: [ask], [help] e [mcve].

Answer (score 6):

O problema é exatamente o que o compilador lhe indica, que não sabe como comparar os dois elementos passados.

Considere uma estrutura que representa um ponto cartesiano num plano 2d:

```
typedef struct {
   int x;
   int y;
} Ponto;
```

Se agora tentarmos criar dois pontos e comparar com `==` não irá funcionar:

```
int main(){
    Ponto p1 = {10, 20};
    Ponto p2 = {10, 20};

    if (p1 == p2){
        printf("iguais");
    }
    else {
        printf("diferentes");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Pois o compilador não sabe como comparar dois pontos. Na verdade o erro:

> no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘Ponto’ and ‘Ponto’)

Só acontece se estiver a compilar em c++, se estiver a compilar em C como devia o erro é diferente, embora signifique o mesmo:

> invalid operands to binary == (have ‘Ponto {aka struct }’ and ‘Ponto {aka struct }’)

A forma de resolver em C é comparar os campos individualmente que para si representam igualdade. Pode até fazer uma função para tal ou talvez se servir de [`memcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcmp/) para comparar a memória toda, mas no fim irá representar a mesma lógica.

No meu exemplo comparando campo a campo ficaria assim:

```
if (p1.x == p2.x && p1.y == p2.y){
    printf("iguais");
}
else {
    printf("diferentes");
}
```

Comparando com `memcmp`:

```
if (memcmp(&p1, &p2, sizeof(Ponto)) == 0){
    printf("iguais");
}
else {
    printf("diferentes");
}
```

Neste ultimo vê que precisa não só de passar o endereço de memoria dos dois elementos a comparar, assim como a quantidade de bytes a comparar em memoria. O retorno é `0` quando ambos os blocos de memória são iguais, no caso quando os dois pontos são iguais. É também importante mencionar que precisa do *header* `<string.h>` para o `memcmp`.

Este tipo de comparações é menos comum pois utiliza todos os campos da estrutura, que em muitos casos não é o que se pretende. E se algum dos campos for um ponteiro a comparação verifica se o ponteiro é igual ou seja se aponta para o mesmo sitio e não se o valor apontado é igual.

[Veja estes dois exemplos no Ideone](https://ideone.com/1BIBWM)

Answer (score 2):

Na linha

```
if (aux->item == x)
```

a expressão `aux->item` é do tipo `TipoItem`, e a variável `x` é do tipo `TipoCelula*`. Não é possível comparar uma estrutura TipoItem (aux->item) com um ponteiro TipoCelula* (aux), portanto o compilador reclama.